# Redirect the document root and a specific page only to another domain

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Might sound confusing, but what I want to achieve is this:

1. If the user visits:

   `www.mydomain.com` (with or without `www.`)

   transfer them to:

   `www.myotherdomain.com/welcome-old-users`
2. At the same time, I want to achieve this:

   If they visit:

   `www.domain.com/about-us` (with or without `www.`)

   transfer them to:

   `www.myotherdomain.com/about-us`

What I have so far is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # To redirect all users to HTTPS 
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
     RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirects all www to non-www
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^www.)?mydomain.com/?$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which works with point #2

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^www.)?mydomain.com/?$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```
>
> Which works with point #2

But the "problem" with this is that it redirects *everything*, not just `/about-us`, which is what you've stated as the requirements for point #2.

`(^www.)?mydomain.com/?$` - You've put the start-of-string anchor (`^`) in the wrong place. This will match any hostname that simply ends in "mydomain.com" (including *any* subdomains and domains that share the same suffix). The `Host` header never ends in a slash, so the `/?` at the end is superfluous.

(And the `RewriteBase` directive is not required here.)

You would need to do something like the following instead, *before* your existing directives, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect "/" (document root) only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.myotherdomain.com/welcome-old-users [R=302,L]

# Redirect "/about-us" only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us$ https://www.myotherdomain.com/$0 [R=302,L]
```

You will need to clear your cache before testing. Test with 302 (temporary) redirects and ensure it is working before changing to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention.

Comment: Works great!! Thank you